# What is the advantage of krausening?

Tags: beer, carbonation, priming, krausen

Krausening seems to be a fair bit of work to the homebrewer with very little return. So, what advantages does krausening bring, other than not having to add any additional sugar to the beer for carbonation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume by krausening you mean priming with gyle.  I've tried it and found no advantages to it whatsoever.  It's a pain to calculate the right amount and depending on the fermentability of the wort you can get varying carb levels.  I've tried priming with a number of things and always come back to sugar (corn or table) as the most reliable and neutral method.

The term krausening is more often used to describe adding actively fermenting wort to beer.  This can be an effective way to reduce diacetyl in a batch.

Comment: Well, I have always used the term "krausen" (perhaps erroneously) to mean prime with gyle. But yes, as far as I can see there is no merit in the procedure other than to allowing you to say that your batch has no added refined sugar.

Comment: I think the difference is that krausening uses actively fermenting wort while priming with gyle uses wort that is not fermenting.  So I guess technically you could krausen to carbonate, but that's not what people usually mean by it.

Answer (score 0):

Krausen refers to either the yeasty foam in the fermenter or a method of priming beer with the wort from the batch that is being primed. gyle is another term for unfermented wort. priming with Krausen allows the beer to adhere to the rheinheitsgebot.

one would assume that Krausen would impart no foreign or undesirable flavors to the beer because it uses it's own maltose to carbonate and condition the final product whereas table sugar or corn syrup are slightly different sugar molecules that produce (albeit slightly) their own flavors.